# Trying to convert sql to linq with subquery

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert this sql to linq:

```
SELECT [t0].[ThreadId] FROM [MessageParticipants] AS [t0]
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT threadId
  FROM [MessageParticipants] AS [t1]
  WHERE ([t1].[UserId] = 23) 
) 
AND ([t0].[UserId] = 3)
```

I have tried converting with LINQPad but I cant get it to work

This almost work:

```
var result = from mp2 in MessageParticipants 
            let x = (from mp in MessageParticipants where mp.UserId == 3 select mp.UserId)
where  x.Contains(23)
select mp2;

result.Dump();
```

The result query of the above LINQ (which is wrong)

```
DECLARE @p0 Int = 23
DECLARE @p1 Int = 3
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[ThreadId], [t0].[UserId], [t0].[CreatedDate], [t0].[MessageId]
FROM [MessageParticipants] AS [t0]
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
  FROM [MessageParticipants] AS [t1]
  WHERE ([t1].[UserId] = @p0) AND ([t1].[UserId] = @p1)
) --> AND should be here not in the inner query
```

Maybe there are a better way ?

I am trying to find if user 23 and user 3 already have an ongoing conversation by finding there threadId.

So the MessageParticipants table looks like this:

```
Id, ThreadId, UserId
--------------------
1    52        23
2    52        3
3    11        20
```

Comment: Strange that your EXISTS condition does not actually filter anything (not uses any info from t0 table at all).

Comment: Your initial query does not make sense because you never join it back to the containing query or you do not care about that only that the table contains some entry where the user is 23? Maybe you can write out in plain English what it is you are trying to return or filter on?

Comment: @Igor added more info

Comment: @n3tx - the answer below works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your sql is a little off, you should use a join on the table to itself and then use a where for the id. Here is the updated sql and underneath the corresponding linq to get the thread id.

```
-- create in memory table for testing
DECLARE @MessageParticipants table (Id INT identity, ThreadId int, UserId int)
insert into @MessageParticipants(ThreadId, UserId) values (52,23), (52,3), (11, 20),(11, 3)

SELECT [t0].[ThreadId]
FROM @MessageParticipants AS [t0]
INNER JOIN @MessageParticipants AS [t1] ON t0.ThreadId = t1.ThreadId
WHERE [t1].[UserId] = 3 AND [t0].[UserId] = 23
```

Linq statement

```
var result = from m1 in MessageParticipants
    join m2 in MessageParticipants on m1.ThreadId equals m2.ThreadId
    where m2.UserId == 3 && m1.UserId == 23
    select m1.ThreadId;

var thread = result.FirstOrDefault();
```